# winforms remove event handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a 3rd party app to produce a chart in my winforms application.

Everything works fine. There is a MouseMove event that works nicely. However sometimes I would like to switch the event of.

Below is my code,

```
    if (_mouseMove)
        _ch.MouseMove += _ch_MouseMove;
```

I have tried,

```
   _ch.MouseMove -= null
```

Error message: Cannot assign to _ch.MouseMove because it is a method group.

How do I stop unhook from this event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `_ch.MouseMove -= _ch_MouseMove;`